# Start different sysyemd services depending on the selected grub option

Tags: systemd, grub

I am relatively new to grub and I was wondering is it possible to make a grub boot option which would start a systemd service.

For example, let's say I want to use my PC both as a server and a desktop, so depending on what I need I select a different boot option. Selecting a server option will start my PC in server mode and start `minecraftd.service` and `httpd.service`. Selecting a desktop option would start `gdm.service`.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Why. Do you really want to shutdown the minecraft server and web-server, when using the desktop.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor well It's just an example, the first thing that came to mind, another use for it might be launching different desktop environments

Answer (score 8):

If you have multiple desktop environments installed, `gdm` should already provide a way to select one of them for your session at login time. If there is a gear icon near the bottom right corner of the screen, click on it for a menu of available session types; that's how it seems to be done in Ubuntu 22.04 at least.

A desktop system is most likely configured to use the systemd target unit `graphical.target` by default. If you want to start the system in GUI-less "server mode", you could use a pre-defined `multi-user.target` instead. If you want set up customized modes, you could define your own target units, with dependencies to services you wish started in that particular mode.

In GRUB, you can select the startup mode by using the `systemd.unit=<name>.target` boot option.

To change from one target to another in a non-persistent way while the system is running, you can use `systemctl isolate <name>.target`. This will make `systemd` start and stop services to match the system state described by the specified target unit.

To set the default boot mode persistently for future reboots, you should use `systemctl set-default <name>.target`.

And finally, any boot options that are not recognized by the kernel will just be displayed in `/proc/cmdline` as-is. So if the above options are not sufficient to you for whatever reason, you could make a script that reads `/proc/cmdline` looking for your custom keywords, and makes changes to the system state according to your requirements. Then just set that script to be executed at a suitable phase of the boot process.